# TimedOut in python-telegram-bot but message is sent

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've got following error while trying to send a message to a specific telegram channel:

```
TimedOut: Timed out
The read operation timed out
```

the method which I used from python-telegram-bot was `send_message`.

Although my bot got this error but it still sent the message to the channel and because I did not catch that exception all data from the message was lost but I really need to remove my messages from that channel after a specific period of time.

Is this OK that the bot sent the message even though it got Timed Out? How can I prevent this from happen again or remove this kind of messages from the channel after being sent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Time out errors mean that TG didn't send a response to your `send_message` request quick enough. It does not necessarily mean that the request wasn't processed - that's why the message may still be sent. However, without response from TG, you don't have the message id of the resulting message and it will be hard to impossible to delete it.

You can try to increase the time that PTB waits for a response from TG. THis can be done in different ways:

- with the `timeout` parameter of `send_message`
- with `Defaults.timeout`, if you're using PTBs `Defaults` setup
- by specifying it via the `request_kwargs` that you pass to `Updater`

You may want to have a look at this [wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Handling-network-errors) on networking.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Answer (score 6):

After a couple of hours reading here and there, and passing timeout=30 to `context.bot.send_audio` and getting an error that says `unknown parameter` even though `send_audio`'s docs clearly states it takes a `timeout` param, I found that you can fix this by passing the timeouts to the Application upon building it:

```
application = ApplicationBuilder()
    .token(bot_data["token"])
    .read_timeout(30)
    .write_timeout(30)
    .build()
```

This fixed my bot. Hope this helps you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where the message was sent but I received an "Timed out" error. I used the `send_media_group` method and solved the problem by adding the `write_timeout=20` parameter. For more details, please refer to the following page: [LINK](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.6/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_media_group).

edit:

The problem is still not resolved. I'm trying with different values for `write_timeout=30` and `read_timeout=5`, so I'll report back. The default value for write_timeout is 20.

edit2:

The code with parameters `write_timeout=35 and read_timeout=20` is now functioning, but I encountered a problem with the "Flood control exceeded. Retry in 12 seconds" error, which I resolved by "catching" the error. When it occurs, I use `time.sleep(60)` and attempt to resend the message.