# Max retries exceeded with url : 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=5.0)'))

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, urllib3

Recently I created a Telegram-bot which the bot works fine at the beginning. Then after several period of time (say few hours), the bot start to throw the below exception which I really don't understand:

```
Error while getting Updates: urllib3 HTTPError SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot1924749319:<mytoken>/getUpdates (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x116208c90>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=5.0)'))
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socks.py", line 809, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
  File "/Library/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socks.py", line 444, in _negotiate_SOCKS5
    self, CONNECT, dest_addr)
  File "/Library/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socks.py", line 524, in _SOCKS5_request
    resp = self._readall(reader, 3)
  File "/Library/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socks.py", line 276, in _readall
    d = file.read(count - len(data))
  File "/Library/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

My code :

```
def papa_BT_scan(context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):
    ws_nonFG_bot_web_scraping.papa_bt_scan(context)

#Server Start
#===========================================================
def server_start(update: telegram.Update, context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):
    print("Telegram_bot_nonFG Started.")
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,text=':)')
    context.job_queue.run_daily(papa_BT_scan,datetime.time(hour=18, minute=00, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong')),context=update.message.chat_id)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":

    REQUEST_KWARGS = {'proxy_url': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150' }
    u = Updater('<myToken>', use_context=True,request_kwargs=REQUEST_KWARGS)
  

    start_handler = CommandHandler('s', server_start,pass_job_queue=True)
    u.dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
    
    u.job_queue.start()
    u.start_polling()
    u.idle()
```

I searched from the internet, most of the people advise to use Proxy / VPN (ExpressVPN) which I have tried but still no use.

Comment: When including a traceback, please include the full traceback instead of truncating it ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TimedOut in python-telegram-bot but message is sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68390839/timedout-in-python-telegram-bot-but-message-is-sent)

Comment: so is that I have to put the 'connect_timeout' to a bigger value (say '10') in REQUEST_KWARGS in the Updater to solve this ?

Comment: As my error message seems saying my bot has been reached the max. number of retries of the connection, ya?

Comment: You don't "have" to, but it's one way to try to avoid this. Not that if this only happens once in a while, I would just not bother with it …

Comment: this struggle me most of the time and it happens everytime when I start the bot !
What about if I slow down my bot ? (Like for example : use time.sleep(2) to slow down the network 'GET' request would help ?

Comment: Does anyone know how many request can be sent in telegram per min? As my bot will request around 40-50 times(driver.get(url) via Selenium) in the upon functions 'papa_bt_scan', not sure if this is related.

Comment: Does anyone is able to help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several back & forth testing, I can resolve the mentioned issue by inputting timeout parameters like below

`u.start_polling(timeout=600)`